Logic Test: The Entry
←Part 1

After I emailed the stranger telling him what he actually did was just to

drive a car

he sent me an email in reply. It read as follows:

Hi there,
Well done on solving my first puzzle for you! The next step is to come to the door at [redacted], and you need to key in the password for the door to open. However, you only get 1 chance. Otherwise, you are permanently locked out. The keypad is a standard QWERTY keyboard. Below are just some miscellaneous facts and a story I wrote for you :-).
Desmos Geometry is a really cool geometry graphing calculator. I'd definitely recommend it. The URL for it in general is https://www.desmos.com/geometry and for a construction, it is followed by a random sequence of 10 characters (digits and numbers only). An example URL would be https://www.desmos.com/geometry/erij7ut5li (please press the link; it'll definitely interest you).
And it's storytime now!
Once a by came up to me, and e sai, "Hey, look here. I can count! 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10!"  I replied to him, "Ell done! But next time, ay 4 as well, ate." The boy told me, "Thanks! That's reat! I'm going to have a icnic now. Have a great day!" "You too!" And then we walked away fom each other, and each of us had a wonderful day.
Good luck!

Since I don't want to stand next to the door for a long time, trying to figure the password out, I am going to do that before I go there. Can you guys help me find the correct password?

Disclaimer:

I'm not a poet. Don't expect my verses to be the best.


→Part 3

Feel free to edit the tags I used.

Can you double-check the "story"? I think one might be missing... (or rather, not missing)

Either it's been fixed or that isn't so; at least, I see the right number.

@Deusovi Sorry I didn't get back to you earlier. I practically went to bed straight after posting the question (the down-under bit in the example desmos link is true). But I just checked it, and I think it should be good.

I don't know whether there's more to it than this, but:

 The missing characters from the "story" are: boy he said 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, well say mate great picnic from. That's 10 alphanumeric characters, suggesting that we go to https://www.desmos.com/geometry/ohd4wsmgpr where indeed we find a Desmos thingy. A note in the left sidebar says too much is hidden; we can reveal the hidden things using the control at top right. We then see lots of probably-irrelevant points and circles, "PASSWORD:" written out, and below that a single red point, one of two red points; the other has an annotation saying "HIGHLY IMPORTANT (maybe)". Selecting the lower red point indicates that it has the (currently not shown) label "IOTA".

So perhaps our password is

 IOTA.


Good job! This is correct!
